# Problems at Plotting the function in 3d System

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I want to plot the function `x=-3` in a 3D System. I've been searching in the internet for hours and found this example :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function = {
X1(\y,\z) = -3;
}]
\begin{axis}[grid,
x={(-0.7071cm,-0.7071cm)},    
y={(1cm,0.0cm)}, 
z={(0cm,1cm)},
axis lines=center,
font=\footnotesize,
xmax=5.4,ymax=5.4,zmax=5.4,
xmin=-5.4,ymin=-5.4,zmin=-5.4,
xlabel=\normalsize$x$,ylabel=\normalsize$y$,zlabel=\normalsize$z$,
major tick style = {black},
minor tick num=1, minor tick style = {very thin},
axis line style = {-latex}, %Pfeilspitzen
%enlargelimits=0.1

% Ebene x=-3
\addplot3 [color=red, surf, semitransparent] {X1(y,z)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The example I got this example was `z=5`, now I wanted to plot this new Code, but when it is not working. when I put `z` anywhere there's the following 
Package PGF Math Error could not parse '' as a floating point number. Is it possible, that the System doesn't see z as a variable ? 
I don't have any other ideas ... 
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

For 3d-plots you need points with three coordinates; `{X1(y,z)}` is just one component. Moreover, the varying parameters are called `x` and `y`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  [declare function = { X1(\y,\z) = -3;} ]
  \begin{axis}%
    [grid,
     % x={(-0.7071cm,-0.7071cm)},    
     % y={(1cm,0.0cm)}, 
     % z={(0cm,1cm)},
     axis lines=center,
     font=\footnotesize,
     xmax=5.4,ymax=5.4,zmax=5.4,
     xmin=-5.4,ymin=-5.4,zmin=-5.4,
     xlabel={\normalsize$x$},
     ylabel={\normalsize$y$},
     zlabel={\normalsize$z$},
     major tick style = {black},
     minor tick num=1, minor tick style = {very thin},
     axis line style = {-latex},
    ]
    \addplot3 [color=red, surf, semitransparent] ({X1(x,y)},x,y);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```